# Unicode signs shown on development page, but not on actual page with same code

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, firefox, unicode

I have a strange Unicode problem with a Wordpress page I am about to create:

(At least with Firefox and IE.)

On the development page http://natzet.kunden.fincha.com I can see the Unicode signs

(before the blue links and in the address field at the bottom)

but not on the actual page http://www.natzet.de, which has the same code.

Does anyone have an idea, how I could solve that - without replacing the signs by images?

Greetings from Leipzig...

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of the part not behaving properly ? and how are you generating the content in it ?, problem might stemming from something else

Comment: Well, that's how it looks for me on http://natzet.kunden.fincha.com: http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/8329/unbenanntvnc.png However, for me the problem is solved - although it is still an interesting example of cross-browser confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is not Unicode characters. You are using "Font Awesome" icons.

On http://natzet.kunden.fincha.com you are loading styles from http://www.natzet.de. And for some reason it cannot load font file: http://www.natzet.de/wp-content/themes/emode/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1 Maybe because of some domain restrictions.

Try to use css files from the same domain.

Comment: That sound's good, thank you. In the meantime the situation has turned. Now it works on the actual page, but not anymore on the developement page - which is of course not a problem.

Comment: Great to see it worked out, but remember, if it just resolved itself and you don't know why, you should be a little more worried cause it'll surely come back in the production env. so it's better to keep on investigating what caused it so you can make sure it never occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Also, try changing the `de-DE` in the `<html>` tag to

`<html lang="de" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">`

let me know if that works

Comment: It didn't work. Meanwhile it doesn't work on the developement page as well. (But that was already the case, before I changed the code.) `<meta ... />` was already in the code.

Comment: hmmm interesting, it works fine with me on all browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) I don't have IE to test unfortunately, but your code seems to be in place, are you sure it's not your own browser causing the issue ? did you try same browsers on another computer ?

Comment: It gets even funnier: I just opened the page in Firefox on another computer, and it didn't work. The page told me, that scripts are disabled at the moment, so I clicked on enable, and now it works.

Comment: Can you give a more exact code on the "script disabled at the moment" ? this might be the issue actually !